# Bash filter text content with strings from another text

Tags: grep

Untill now I used everytime to filter, `grep` command

```
[root@host tests]# cat e
1
2
3
4
5
[root@host tests]# cat e | grep -Ev '2|3' > filtered.txt

[root@host tests]# cat filtered.txt
1
4
5
[root@host tests]#
```

But right now I have a large file that needs to be filtered with hundred of strings from another file. How can I do it?

Comment: `grep -f another_file large_file` maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you could just use grep with the following option

> ```
>    -f FILE, --file=FILE
>           Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  If this option is used multiple times or is combined with the -e (--regexp) option, search for all patterns given.  The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches
>           nothing.
> ```

You will also want to use both `-F` (use patterns as plain strings in the comparisons, not regular as expressions) and `-x` (compare complete lines, not substrings).  If not `-x`, then `-w` (compare only whole words).

Comment: cat e | grep -Evf strings > filtered.txt ; I used this and it works.

Comment: @JohnDoe `grep -v -f strings e` would look better.  The `-E` is not needed. The `cat` is not needed. You probably want `-x` and `-F` too though.

Comment: @Kusalananda I will check that too. Thankyou.